# Spring MVC Controller firing 5 times per request! Why?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, controller

guys!
I have some services that should fire once a day. But for some reason when TWS fire the job it execute 5 times, with 15 minutes between each execution.
I don´t use any kind of schedule in my project.

The most strange part is that when I call from my browser the same URL the method execute only one time, but when TWS execute then we have that strange behavior.

```
 @Controller
 public class ArquivoController {

    Calendar cal = null;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("arquivoService")
    private ArquivoServiceImpl arquivoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/valida")
    public String valida(Locale locale,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute Busca busca) throws Exception {

        String indReprocessa = "";
        String seqArq = (String) request.getParameter("Processar");

        try {
            logger.info("Carregando CDN...");
            model.put("cdn",new CDN());


            arquivoService.validaArquivos(busca,seqArq,indReprocessa);

            model.addAttribute(class.atributoDeRetornoDoWebService.value(), class.sucesso.value());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute(class.atributoDeRetornoDoWebService.value(), class.erro.value());
        }
        //return Paginas.home.name();
        return class.paginaDeRetornoDoWebService.value();
    }
 }
```

when I call the method in my browser:

http://server/contextName/valida

Fire only once.

if TWS fire by:
/appl/share/xxx/tws-chamada-wsrest.sh http://server/contextName/valida

it fires 5 times with 15 minutes interval.

Here shell script content.

```
 URL_APLICACAO=$1

 ##############################
 RESULTADO_WS=$( /cygdrive/d/jobs/bin/wget.exe $URL_APLICACAO -nv -q --no-proxy -O arquivo.log)

 RETORNO= grep -c "RESULTADO_WS 1" arquivo.log;

 echo $RETORNO
```

I´m using tomcat 7.0.57. I really need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the "problem".

wget have some default proprieties that explain thar behavior. By default wget get have a read timout of 900 seconds (15 minutes) and have a retry or 5 times.

I just have to set de parameters:
--read-timeout=0 (to disable timeout, in my case)
--tries=1 (to execute only once)

```
RESULTADO_WS=$(wget $URL_APLICACAO -nv -q --no-proxy --read-timeout=0 --tries=1 -O arquivo.log)
```

I hope that help someone.